# I need help with trying to answer this question. I know I have to find the derivative; but I do not know what to do after that.

Tags: calculus

Use implicit differentiation to find the slope of the tangent line to the curve y/x-5y=x^3-5 at the point (1,-4/-19)

Comment: If you can find the derivative, then just evaluate at $x = 1$, $y = 4/19$.

Comment: the derivative is y'(x) = 3 x^3+(1/x-30 x^2) y+75 x y^2              I plugged in 1,4/19 and got 49, but it says it is wrong.

Comment: Assuming that's right, set $x = 1$ and $y = 4/19$ in that equation, and that gives you $dy/dx$ there. Can you relate that to the tangent line?

Comment: everybody asking questions here "needs help trying to answer this question." Putting that in your title just makes readers wade through redundant information...

Comment: Is that $\frac{y}{x-5y}$ or $\frac{y}{x}-5y$?

Comment: You could make the headline a bit more informative about the question itself and tell what you have done in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to think of $y$ as a function of $x$, i.e., apply the Chain Rule:
$D[y/x-5y]=D[x^3-5]\implies\frac d{dx}[\frac {y(x)} x]-\frac d{dx}[5y(x)]=\frac d{dx}[x^3]-\frac d{dx}[5]\implies \frac {-y} {x^2}\frac {dy}{dx}-5y\frac {dy}{dx}=3x^2$.

Now solve for $\frac {dy}{dx}$ and apply the initial conditions for a specific solution.